# Is there a way MySQLMaxValueIncrementer connects to multiple datasources in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-tasklet

I have 2 datasources in my project datasource1 connects to datahost1 and datasource2 connects to datahost 2. I have 2 jobs firing for datasource1 and datasource 2 , now the MySQLMaxValueIncrementer should connect to datasource1 to get next incremental Id from datasource1 and for second job it should get from second datasource. Since there is only one MySQLMaxValueIncrementer it is connecting to single datasource. Is there any way we can solve this problem by dynamicalluy saying to use datasource based on condition at runtime

Answer (score 0):

The `JobRepository` can be configured with a single `DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer` (through a `DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory`).

If you want to use the same `JobRepository` for both jobs, then you need to provide a custom incrementer that is able to handle two datasources.

Otherwise, you would need to create a separate `JobRepository` for each job.